# Include product category in Magento order emails

Tags: php, magento

I'd like the ability to list the category name alongside the product in the New Order transactional email like shown in the screenshot below.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must overload the block  in Magento.

Have a look at this topic : http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/14692/

And use the block for email product list :

- **File** : app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Block/Order/Email/Itemps.php
- **Class** : Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Email_Items.php
- **Identifier** : sales/order_email_items